# SSIS import defaults a field to nvarchar(max)

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-2017

I have an Excel file that that I import into SQL using the import wizard (SQL Server 2017). I am letting the wizard create the table. Several of the columns that are created default to `nvarchar(max)`. However, when I look at the data in the source Excel file, none of those columns seem to contain a large amount of data (certainly nothing larger than `nvarchar(4000)`).

Initially, instead of letting the wizard create the table for me, I was pointing it to a pre-created table where the columns defaulting to `nvarchar(max)` by the wizard are set to `nvarchar(4000)`. When I do that though the import fails with an error message

> The binding status was `DT_NTEXT`. The data flow column type is `DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION`.
>
> The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.

Why does this happen?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the Excel columns?   Sounds like they are some type that automatically translates to NTEXT.

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on the Excel Source in data flow task and click on the `Show Advanced Editor`, visit each of the the `output columns` datatypes and change them to a `varchar(255)` or something that is non-unicode so as to run test.

Then create destination table using the automatically generated script and see if flow works.

Regards-